# Spring boot - downloading xlsx file - cannot open

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to create an endpoint that returns xlsx file to download.

When I'm trying to open this generated file with OpenOffice then everything works fine.
It doesn't work with Microsoft Excel, when trying to open it shows something like "excel cannot open the file due to invalid format".

Unfortunatelly I have no idea why is that.
I did try (as you can see in the code snippet) different content types.

This is sample of my code:

```java
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.springframework.http.*;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/xls")
    public class XlsController {

        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get() {
            try {
                final byte[] data = getData();
                String fileName = "test.xlsx";

                HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
                header.setContentLength(data.length);
    //            header.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8"));
    //            header.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
                header.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
                header.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
                header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

                return new ResponseEntity<>(data, header, HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }

        private byte[] getData() throws IOException {

            String[][] data = {
                    {"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"},
                    {"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2"}
            };

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
                int rowNumber = 0;
                int totalNumberOfColumns = 4;
                int totalNumberOfRows = 2;

                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test Sheet");
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                Cell cell;

                for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfRows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < totalNumberOfColumns; j++) {
                        cell = row.createCell(i);
                        cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                baos.close();
            }

            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s best to take a MINIMUM example first, so let’s find out whether the problem is with the File, or with the web setup.   So when you have the `byte[] data`, write that directly to a file - can you open that file in Excel?

Comment: Incidentally, try-with-resources can handle multiple variables, so you can move that `baos` declaration Into that `try`, so allowing you to get rid of that `finally`.

Comment: Nothing in your code writes something into your `ByteArrayOutputStream baos`, does it?

Comment: Do you want to generate a `XLS` or a `XLSX` file? You've got code for XLSX but the mime type of XLS....

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you, I did miss that line `workbook.write(baos);`. I will post an answer with working getData() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is improved method, It's working now, thank you.

Changes:

- added `workbook.write(baos);` line
- fixed for loops

```java
 private byte[] getData() throws IOException {

        String[][] data = {
                {"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"},
                {"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2"}
        };

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            int totalNumberOfColumns = 4;
            int totalNumberOfRows = 2;

            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test Sheet");

            for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfRows; i++) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
                Cell cell;
                
                for (int j = 0; j < totalNumberOfColumns; j++) {
                    cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                }
            }

            workbook.write(baos);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            baos.close();
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```